# Sorting an array in descending order but a method is predefined we can only call it

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

Sorting an array in descending order but a method is predefined we can only call it. we can not modify it. It reverses the value in reverse order at that particular index.
We call this method by passing an array and index value like int funSort(int array[], int indexValue) and it will return a reverse the array value at that particular indexed by using this method we sort this array by calling again and again in descending order.

for example:-

```
int method1(int array[],int indexValue){ .... }

int []array=new int[]{1,34,12,32,45,6,67};
//their indexed value 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 

// Now we call it

method1(array,2);

//it return [12,34,1,32,45,6,67]

//like we again call it 

method1(int AboveArray[],int randomIndex(3));

//it return [32,1,34,12,45,6,67]

// in final array descending arder array[67,45,34,32,12,6,1]
```

Comment: in which language you are looking?

Comment: I want this solution in Java or C language please solve it soon ......

Answer (score -1):

In c# you can do like this

```
 int[] array = new int[] { 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 };
 Array.Sort<int>(array,
                new Comparison<int>(
                        (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)
                ));
```

or....

```
 int[] array = new int[] { 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 };
 Array.Sort<int>( array );
 Array.Reverse( array );
```

or using LINQ

```
array = array.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToArray();
```

in javascript it is  easy

```
array.sort().reverse()
```

Comment: I think you do not understand my problem please i request you read again and then answer me

Comment: I do not want to just sort an array and return its descending order , I want these things to be done by predefined function which is given Method1 and its return reverse of array at particular passing indexed

Comment: prediction defined method1 which is given in question not in any language so please understand my problem.....